# HTML inside Microsoft Lync 2013 Conversation Window Extension

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, lync

I am developing Microsoft Lync 2013 Conversation Window Extension. This is XAML app. I need to show html inside this app.

I have found a good example which works fine for browser (http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/integrating-html-into-silverlight-applications), but in Lync it just opens the windows with 100% loading circle.

This is the registry which is used to add app to Lync

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Lync\Security\Trusted Sites]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Lync\Security\Trusted Sites\http://localhost/HTMLAndSilverlight.Web/HTMLAndSilverlightTestPage.aspx]
"https"=dword:00000000
"http"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Communicator\ContextPackages]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\ServerName]
"file"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Communicator\ContextPackages\{2FF4307C-D205-490A-8CF5-3B4979E3ED96}]
"Name"="CWE Demo App"
"InternalURL"="http://localhost/HTMLAndSilverlight.Web/HTMLAndSilverlightTestPage.aspx"
"ExternalURL"="http://localhost/HTMLAndSilverlight.Web/HTMLAndSilverlightTestPage.aspx"
"InstallLink"="http://localhost/HTMLAndSilverlight.Web/HTMLAndSilverlightTestPage.reg"
"ExtensibilityWindowSize"=dword:00000000
```

XAML app for simple case works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Lync\Security\Trusted Sites\localhost

(and not the full http://localhost/ etc)